# Similarity / distance between many pairs of matrices

Tags: r, vectorization, distance, similarity

I want to quantify group similarity by computing the mean of the distance between all sets of (multidimensional) points in each pair.

I can do this easily enough manually for each pair of groups manually like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(proxy)

# dummy data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100,0,4), 
                  y = rnorm(100,1,5), 
                  z = rbinom(100, 1, 0.1))
df2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100,-1,3), 
                  y = rnorm(100,0,6), 
                  z = rbinom(100, 1, 0.1))
df3 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100,-30,4), 
                  y = rnorm(100,10,2), 
                  z = rbinom(100, 1, 0.9))

# compute distance (unscaled, uncentred data)
dist(df1, df2, method = "gower") %>% mean
dist(df1, df3, method = "gower") %>% mean
dist(df2, df3, method = "gower") %>% mean
```

But I'd like to somehow vectorise this as my actual data has 30+ groups. A simple for loop can achieve this like so:

```
# combine data and scale, centre
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  mutate(id = rep(1:3, each = 100))
df <- df %>% 
  select(-id) %>%
  transmute_all(scale) %>% 
  add_column(id = df$id)

# create empty matrix for comparisons
n <- df$id %>% unique %>% length
m <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)

# loop through each pair once
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:i) { #omit top right corner
    if(i == j) {
      m[i,j] <- NA #omit diagonal
    } else {
      m[i,j] <- dist(df[df$id == i,1:3], df[df$id == j,1:3], method = "gower") %>% mean
    }
  }
}

m
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,]        NA        NA   NA
[2,] 0.2217443        NA   NA
[3,] 0.8446070 0.8233932   NA
```

However, this method scales predictably badly; a quick benchmark suggests this will take 90+ hours with my actual data which has 30+ groups with 1000+ rows per group.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution, or perhaps a fundamentally different way to frame the problem which I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take each pair of groups, concatenate them, and then just calculate the dissimilarity matrix within that group. Obviously this means you're comparing a group to itself to an extent, but it may still work for your use case, and with `daisy` it is reasonably quick for your size of data.

```
library(cluster)

n <- 30
groups <- vector("list", 30)

# dummy data
set.seed(123)
for(i in 1:30) {
  groups[[i]] = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000,ceiling(runif(1, -10, 10)),ceiling(runif(1, 2, 4))), 
                           y = rnorm(1000,ceiling(runif(1, -10, 10)),ceiling(runif(1, 2, 4))), 
                           z = rbinom(1000,1,runif(1,0.1,0.9)))
}

m <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)

# loop through each pair once
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:i) { #omit top right corner
    if(i == j) {
      m[i,j] <- NA #omit diagonal
    } else {
      # concatenate groups
      dat <- rbind(df_list[[i]], df_list[[j]])

      # compute all distances (between groups and within groups), return matrix
      mm <- dat %>% 
        daisy(metric = "gower") %>%
        as.matrix

      # retain only distances between groups
      mm <- mm[(nrow(df_list[[i]])+1):nrow(dat) , 1:nrow(df_list[[i]])]

      # write mean distance to global comparison matrix
      m[i,j] <- mean(mm)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thom, `daisy`'s implementation of Gower is blindingly fast compared to `proxy`; for 3 groups with 1000 rows, your method takes 2.4s vs. 146.5s for mine -- even though it also computes within-group distance. I'm just going to add a bit to your code showing how to keep only the between-group distances before computing the mean as they're all that I'm interested in here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will do well but here's another approach. You use `ls` to obtain the names of matrices, `combn` to generate pairs of two, and then `get` to obtain the matrices for calculating `dist`

```
do.call(rbind,
        combn(ls(pattern = "df\\d+"), 2, FUN = function(x)
            data.frame(pair = toString(x),
                       dist = mean(dist(get(x[1]), get(x[2]), method = "gower")),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            simplify = FALSE
        ))
#      pair      dist
#1 df1, df2 0.2139304
#2 df1, df3 0.8315169
#3 df2, df3 0.8320911
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @d.b. Unfortunately, this isn't much faster; using the example above with a group size of 500, it takes 32.16s on my machine versus 32.84s for the for loop.

Comment: @jogall, it seems like the most time consuming step is `dist`. Unless there's other packages that have faster implementations for that `dist`, there may not be much that can be done to improve speed.

Comment: Yes it seems so -- I guess I'm hoping someone may be able to suggest a conceptually different way to approach the problem, e.g. some kind of valid shortcut that can be taken to compute group averages instead of computing distance between each pair of vectors in a set.

Comment: @jogall, check out `gower::gower_dist()`. It seems to be faster but gives different values.

Answer (score 1):

`proxy` can work with lists of matrices as input,
you only need to define a wrapper function that does what you want:

```
nested_gower <- function(x, y, ...) {
  mean(proxy::dist(x, y, ..., method = "gower"))
}

proxy::pr_DB$set_entry(
  FUN = nested_gower,
  names = c("ngower"),
  distance = TRUE,
  loop = TRUE
)

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
proxy::dist(df_list, df_list, method = "ngower")
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] 0.1978306 0.2139304 0.8315169
[2,] 0.2139304 0.2245903 0.8320911
[3,] 0.8315169 0.8320911 0.2139049
```

This will still be slow,
but it should be faster than `for` loops in plain R
(`proxy` uses C in the background).

**Important**: note that the diagonal of the resulting cross-distance matrix doesn't have zeros.
If you were to call `dist` like `proxy::dist(df_list, method = "ngower")`,
`proxy` will assume that `distance(x, y) = distance(y, x)` (symmetry),
and that `distance(x, x) = 0`,
the latter of which is not true in this case.
Passing two arguments to `dist` prevents this assumption.
If you really don't care about the diagonal,
pass only one argument to save some extra time by avoiding the calculations of the upper triangular.
Alternatively, if you do care about the diagonal but still want to avoid calculating the upper triangular,
call `dist` first with one argument and then call `proxy::dist(df_list, df_list, method = "ngower", pairwise = TRUE)`.

Side note: if you want to imitate this behavior with the `gower` package (as suggested by d.b),
you could define the wrapper function as:

```
nested_gower <- function(x, y, ...) {
  distmat <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(y_row) {
      gower::gower_dist(x, y[y_row, , drop = FALSE], ...)
  })

  mean(distmat)
}
```

However, the values returned seem to change depending on how many records are passed to the functions,
so it's hard to tell what would be the best approach.

*Use `proxy::pr_DB$delete_entry("ngower")` first if you want to redefine a function in `proxy`.

---

If you prefer `proxy`'s version of the Gower cross-distance matrix,
it occurs to me that you could leverage some of the functionality of my `dtwclust` package to do the calculations in parallel:

```
library(dtwclust)
library(doParallel)

custom_dist <- new("tsclustFamily", dist = "ngower", control = list(symmetric = TRUE))@dist

workers <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(workers)

distmat <- custom_dist(df_list)

stopCluster(workers); registerDoSEQ()
```

This *might* be faster for your actual use case
(not so much for the small sample data here).
Same caveat about the diagonal
(so use `custom_dist(df_list, df_list)` or `custom_dist(df_list, pairwise = TRUE)`).
See section 3.2 [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/vignettes/parallelization-considerations.html) and the documentation of `tsclustFamily` if you'd like more info.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Alexis, I had no idea you could define wrapper functions with `proxy` so this is really useful. However, I accepted @Thom's answer (with a little modification) simply because it's much quicker and the total computation time was the biggest obstacle I was facing -- for a sample of 3 groups with 1000 rows each, that method takes 2.4s vs 89.4s for this one.

Comment: @jogall You could still just embed the suggested procedure with `daisy` inside `nested_gower` and let `proxy` do the looping.